# Actionscript 3 compare two MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I dynamically add MovieClips to an DisplayObjectContainer. Some of these MovieClips loop through all children of DisplayObjectContainer to check gravitation and collision. Though, when I check if the current child is not equal to the caller MovieClip it seems to check the type only.

So basically, when I check MovieClip equality it seems to check the type only.

Main.as:

```
var planet:Planet = new Planet(holder);
planet.x = 0;
planet.y = 0;
planet.spawn();

var planet2:Planet = new Planet(holder);
planet2.x = 50;
planet2.y = 50;
planet2.spawn();
```

Planet.as:

```
public class Planet {
    public var x:Number = 0;
    public var y:Number = 0;

    private var _holder:DisplayObjectContainer;
    private var _mc:MovieClip;

    public function Planet(holder:DisplayObjectContainer) {
        _holder = holder;

        _mc = new PlanetMovieClip();
        _mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }

    public function spawn():void {
        _holder.addChild(_mc);
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(evt:Event):void {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < _holder.numChildren; i++) {
            var child:MovieClip = _holder.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;

            // the other planet never passes this check
            if(child !== _mc) {
                trace('child is not the same');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So am I doing something wrong, should I approach an other method or should I just add an property that generates a random token used for identification?

Comment: what if you remove `as MovieClip;` in `_holder.getChildAt(i);`

Comment: What's this supposed to do: `var planet:Planet(holder);` ?

Comment: @mgraph That kinda works. Because of your comment I realized that I'm using the wrong approach! Thanks! If you add your comment as an answer I'll set it as correct answer because it did in fact solve my problem ;)

Comment: @weltraumpirat It was a typo because I rewrite the script for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should remove `as MovieClip;` in `_holder.getChildAt(i);`

Comment: @loxxy i put it as comment, `Tim S.` said that was helpful

Comment: It actually worked because Tim S. is using !== instead of != for comparing both objects. As !== is only true if the objects AND their datatypes are equals. The cast to a movieclip results in comparing a MovieClip with a PlanetMovieClip which always results false.

Answer (score 0):

I would change !== with !=
The rest of your code seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have error in the code you have given to create Planet movieclip.

It should be

```
    var planet:Planet = new Planet(holder);
    planet.x = 0;
    planet.y = 0;
    planet.spawn();

    var planet2:Planet = new Planet(holder)
    planet2.x = 50;
    planet2.y = 50;
    planet2.spawn();
```

Did you check for null in Planet.as ?

```
if(child!=null) { 
     if(child !== _mc)
        trace('child is not the same');
     else 
        trace("child same");                
}
```

And ofcourse you can always assign some unique name to the movieclips, and use it for comparing.

Comment: The first thing was basically a typo in rewriting the script to post here. I've edited it. But checking null for a MovieClip still doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: did you try assigning a unique name to the movie clip and check against it ?